# Understanding window resize event with scope.$apply with $watch on a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I found this http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/ and I am able to get it works.

```
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return {
                'h': w.height(),
                'w': w.width()
            };
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
```

But the problem is, I don't know how it works? Why `scope.$apply()`? What is the purpose of it? Why `scope.getWindowDimensions` will get updated when window is resized?

Comment: so what is wrong with the code here?

Comment: @Claies there is nothing wrong with the code. It's just I don't know how it works and hope to get the understanding here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `$watch` can be a string or a function. If you pass a string like `$scope.$watch('foo'`, it is watching `$scope.foo`. If you pass a function, then the watch is on the return value of the function. Angular will fire the function on every $digest cycle. If the returned value is different than the previous $digest cycle, the callback function (second parameter) will fire. In this code, `scope.getWindowDimensions` is a function being passed and when its return value is different, the callback will fire. So, every $digest cycle, if `w.height()` or `w.width()` have changed, the callback is fired, and the $scope properties are updated. Finally, you have the `true` (third) parameter set, which makes the $watch a deep watch, so that Angular will thoroughly check the object, to tell whether it is identical, even though it's a new object every time. Without this, Angular will do a quick check, see that it's a new object, and start an infinite loop.

```
scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
  scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
}, true);
```

Lastly, the code above won't do anything unless a $digest cycle is triggered. The following code attaches an event listener to `window` so that the function is fired when the window is resized. `scope.$apply()` just triggers a $digest cycle so that `scope.getWindowDimensions` will be checked, and the callback will be fired.

```
w.bind('resize', function () {
  scope.$apply();
});
```

With all that said, I find this code to be a bit awkward. This is how I'd write it. This way makes a lot more sense to me - easier to read, and should be more performant.

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return function (scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);
    w.bind('resize', function () {
      // trigger $digest when window is resized and call `update` function
      scope.$apply(update);
    });
    update(); // initial setup
    function update() {
      var height = w.height();
      var width = w.width();
      scope.windowHeight = height;
      scope.windowWidth = width;
      scope.style = function() {
        return {
          'height': (height - 100) + 'px',
          'width': (width - 100) + 'px'
        };
      };
    }   
  }
})
```

[**Live demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7krjjwm/)

Comment: Instead of scope.$apply can we just use $timeout which is neater way of triggering the digest cycle. calling scope.$apply is considered anti-pattern

Comment: @mohamedrias i don't think so :-P Can you explain your point.

Comment: @mohamedrias woah, since when? `$timeout` is considered a hack =D Considering Angular says to use `$apply` for DOM events and uses it internally itself, I'm not convinced at all.

Comment: @m59 yup i am agree with you :-)

Comment: @mohamedrias yup there is no where written scope.$apply is anti pattern in this situation.

Comment: Consider the second point : if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()  Please tell me where it says to use $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: @mohamedrias do you understand what that code does? "it means your $scope.$apply() isn't high enough in the call stack." That says you need to use `$scope.$apply()` appropriately (like I do). It doesn't say DON'T use it. It says USE IT RIGHT.

Comment: As far as i know we need $apply to run manully if we are running something out of scope of angular but want it to reflect it inside the scope.Here we are running bind which is jquery function so definitely out of scope of angular and need to $apply for digest cycle .

Comment: cool. May be I'm wrong. I remember in another question inside directive when i used scope.$apply I got comments to avoid using it. that's the reason why i mentioned it here. Thanks @m59

Comment: @mohamedrias I understand. I think a lot of people do say that. It's hard to work out what the truth is sometimes. I try to really question and fully understand any advice I take.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its better to google first and then ask your doubt here but anyways if you didn't get anything from it here is the summary:-

```
w.bind('resize',callback)
```

function binds the resize event of window to w therefore if window resize value of `w.height()` and `w.width()` change So you are having `scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions,callback);` watch the changes in scope.getWindowDimensions which is definately gonna change on changing the window size which in turn calll the  callback function.

Now why we are using `scope.$apply();`The reson is simple w.bind is out of scope of angular so you need to run the digest cycle which is going to run manually by `scop.$apply`.

Sorry for bad english :-P